# ClientProtocolException in httpClient.execute(httpget, responseHandler)

Tags: java, android, http, http-get

I am using the following code to request xml from a web server:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
try 
{
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://63.255.173.242/get_public_tbl.cgi?A=1");              
    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    System.out.println(responseBody);
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally 
{
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

I get a clientProtocolException when I call httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).  The url works just fine in a web browser, it returns the xml and the browser displays it.

Any ideas why I would get a clientProtocolException and yet the browser handles it just fine?

Edit 1:

Looking at the protocol exception the detail message is: "The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response".  I cannot change the web server that I am hitting.  Is there a way to ignore this and just access the response?

Edit 2:

I have found that the server is not sending back a complete header.  Is there a way to access the contents of the response even when a broken header is returned?

Edit 3: I edited the ip address to be the real IP address I am hitting.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what was the solution to it . i am getting the same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your code seems to be correct, you have to figure out: Is this the client's fault (invalid request), or the server's fault (invalid response). To do that, use a [http trace utitlity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944862/http-trace-utitlity/12967817#12967817) and compare the requests of a browser to that of your client. You'll also be able to see the raw response from the server, if there is any. If you can't figure it out then, add the raw request and response to your question and someone might be able to help.

Comment: I know that the server is not sending back a valid response as the headers are not complete.  But the server cannot change. It is a 3rd party server that I am implementing functionality for.  Regardless, I know there has to be a way to access the raw response and sort out the data that I want.  What I have posted is my request.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I found that the server is not sending a header at all. The best solution was to directly communicate with sockets.

Comment: @Kevin what you did finally with this problem , i am getting the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code with my ip address. There is no error in code. I just changed `ResponseHandler` to `BasicResponseHandler`.

check this

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try 
    {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.MyServer.com/get_public_tbl.cgi?A=1");               
        BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();//Here is the change
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: That's a good improvement to my code, but does not address the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add your own response interceptor, where you can add or delete headers, or print some debug info

```
hc.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);
    }
});
```

Comment: I added a response interceptor, but the process method does not get called before the protocol exception is thrown.  If I hit a server that sends a valid header, the process method is called.  Any other ideas?

Comment: U can add `new HttpRequestInterceptor` with method `void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context)` same way, then print and compare headers of request that goes from browser and from ur code. May be server w8 "Accept-Encoding", "gzip" header or smth else

Answer (score 1):

Check your headers which you set in the client, re-verify both key and value of headers. In my case I was using "csrf" param instead of "Cookie".

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, ClientProtocolException
Apparently the server didn't have the target web service SSL
so it was wrong SSL configuration,

Underlying error was:

```
  java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

After adding the truststore to java this error disappeared.

hope it help someone.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I have removed the below dependency from the pom file and it fixed the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
```