# http trace utility

Tags: json, http, proxy, trace, packet-sniffers

I need to trace/sniff http traffic from other machines (for example from  my android phone or ios device). In the past I used MSSOAPT (described here http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/microsoft-soap-trace-tool) and it was perfect, I need something similar, and now it should have syntax highlighting for json and be able to unzip content :).

I would like to tell my android to go to http://my.machine.home/Foo?bar and this proxy should forward this to  other server such as http://google.com/Foo?bar and it should print complete trafic.

I would prefer if the solution would not require proxy configuration on my device, but just would forward all requests sent to the process.

and it does not have to be free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [charle proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) it is very easy to use and has all your requirements fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as a great free tool.

On other platforms, you could use the free and open-source [WebScarab](http://owasp.com/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project). The UI is not as easy to use as Fiddler, and although it runs on Windows, I rather prefer Fiddler there.