# How to use POST in sending data in JSON in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, post

I don't know if I'm doing the right way of sending data in JSON using POST. I want to send a single data on JSONObject "ReportCode". I got this so far? Please tell me what's wrong on my code and what should I need to do to pass the data in JSON. Thanks.

```
public class DoPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
Exception exception = null;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context mContext = null;
BufferedReader in;
InputStream is;

public DoPost(Context context) {

    mContext = context;

}

protected void onPreExecute() 
{     
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Validating....");
    progressDialog.show();              
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) 
{
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jObject.put("ReportCode","13-T001");

        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ReportData", jObject.toString()));

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://phsjulchs4.tias.com.ph:1217/api/report");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();


    }catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("ClientServerDemo", "Error:", e);
    exception = e;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), 5).show();
    }

return true;    

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();   
    //Update the UI
    if(exception != null){

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sent", 6).show();
    }else{
    //  mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, S_2nd_Main.class));

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is it not passing or what is the problem ?

Comment: I got this error 07-31 13:33:47.906: E/ClientServerDemo(6803): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException at HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13149239/430480) for similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you see the options for all  the valid parameters for the [.execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) function on `DefaultHttpClient`, then none of them just have one `HttpPost` object as input parameters. So that's why you are experiencing the error. Try to make the input parameters correct. Hope that helps you understand the issue.