# org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: java, android, xml

Its been long I am stuck with this issue, from my androidApp HTTP get used to work fine with my Cable Modem HTTP server but at client place with **linux** **mini_httpd** I am getting this org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException soon after

```
httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

I did lot of research before posting this question here, before I was not setting contentType as xml but I am doing it

```
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml"); but still struggling with same error.
```

Detailed code is as below

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 25000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

   HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);          

   httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
   httpget.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
   httpget.setParams(httpParameters);

   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response = null;
   try {
       response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
       StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
       if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
           Log.d("Http response", "response string got");

           /* parse the response received from server */
           try {
               cmInfo = xmlParser.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
               Log.d("Http Response","back in main");
           } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
               Log.d("parse:", "XmlPullParserException");
               e1.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               Log.d("parse:", "IOException");
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errMsg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errMsg1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Refused from server or Connection Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Kindly suggest what to be done or is there any workaround.

And here is the logcat

```
03-18 18:41:08.246: D/getWifiDetails: cmURL:(32090): http://192.168.0.1:50010?
03-18 18:41:08.246: D/WizardYourWifiActivity: URL-(32090): http://192.168.0.1:50010?get_data=PARM_WIFI_SSIDNAME_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_SSIDNAME_5G,PARM_WIFI_SECURITYMODE_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_SECURITYMODE_5G,PARM_WIFI_PASSPHRASE_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_PASSPHRASE_5G,PARM_WIFI_MODE_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_MODE_5G,PARM_WIFI_POWER_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_POWER_5G,PARM_WIFI_CHANNEL_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_CHANNEL_5G,PARM_WIFI_GUEST_NW_EN_2_4G,PARM_WIFI_GUEST_NW_EN_5G
03-18 18:41:08.707: W/System.err(32090): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at com.arrisi.selfinstall.wizard.WizardYourWifiActivity.doCustomCreate(WizardYourWifiActivity.java:98)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at com.arrisi.selfinstall.wizard.BaseWizardActivity.onCreate(BaseWizardActivity.java:44)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-18 18:41:08.713: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:162)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:178)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
03-18 18:41:08.714: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
03-18 18:41:08.715: W/System.err(32090):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-18 18:41:08.715: W/System.err(32090):    ... 17 more
```

Comment: The problem is not in the client, the server is returning a response with incorrect headers, you should trace the raw server response. Anyway, if you want to make a simple request don't have make sense using Apache Http Components, use the Android's default HttpURLConnection.

Comment: @vzamanillo I have edited my question with the response from server. Server is actually responding with the proper message as per expectation but at client code it is throwing ClientProtocolException

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684739/, trace the server response to see the http headers returned by the server, is not a fault in your client but the client is who warn you about the error.

Comment: yes looks like there is a problem in response structure

Answer (score 0):

As suspected this problem was due to the improper response from the server. Basically

```
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

was not being set by the server that was actually creating the problem at my http client side.
I used HttpURLConnection in place of appache.http as suggested in other stackOverFlow answers but that actually did not solve the problem but it helped me to narrow down the problem.

Thanks @vzamanillo for ur help